# Cannot get value from Reactive Form after Disable

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Edit: The problem of this issue is because of "disable" not "patchValue", so I modify my title to natch the problem.

I have a reactive Form which have to update amount field dynamically based on another field's value. The Update part works fine by using `patchValue`, however, once `patchValue` is fired, I'm not able to get the value of amount field.

My Form:

```
basicInfoForm: this.formBuilder.group({
    lc_currency :'',
    lc_amount :'',
  }),
```

My main Html:

```html
<nav>
  <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-basic-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-basic" role="tab">
      Internal Info
    </a>
  </div>
</nav>
  
<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-basic" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-basic-tab">
  <form [formGroup]="extraInfoForm">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label required-field">change amount?</label>
         <select class="form-control" formControlName="doModAmt"
              (change)="onDoModAmtChanged($event)" required>
           <option value="Y">Y</option>
           <option value="N">N</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <app-amd-lc-ext-action-basic [basicInfoForm]="basicInfoForm"></app-amd-lc-ext-action-basic>
  </div>
</div>
```

My tab HTML:

```html
<div style="width:90%;margin:auto">
 <div class="form-horizontal" id="div_form">
  <div [formGroup]="basicInfoForm">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="form-group">
       <label class="control-label required-field">New LC Currency</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly=true formControlName="lc_currency" required>
  </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3">
     <div class="form-group">
       <label class="control-label required-field">New LC Amount</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="lc_amount" required>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

onDoModAmtChanged method on main HTML's ts.

```js
onDoModAmtChanged(event: any){
    if(event.target.value == 'N'){
      this.basicInfoForm.controls['lc_amount'].patchValue("100000");
      this.basicInfoForm.controls['lc_amount'].disable();
    }else{
      this.basicInfoForm.controls['lc_amount'].enable();
    }
  }
```

Doing '`this.basicInfoForm.value`' on main ts, when `onDoModAmtChanged` is not fired (`patchValue` is not fired), the value is:`{"lc_currency":"USD","lc_amount":"50000"}`, which is correct.

But once `patchValue` is fired, `lc_amount` goes missing, only `lc_currency` left :{"lc_currency":"USD"}

Can anyone help? Thank you very much.

Comment: when `onDoModAmtChanged ` is fired , does `lc_amount` formControl get disabled ? ( in case of  `event.target.value == 'N'` )

Comment: @MohamedAliRACHID Yes, lc_amount formControl get disabled. Oh gosh, the problem is "disabled" part, isn't it?

Comment: yes exactly , check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are disabling the `lc_amount` control, you cannot see its value when calling `this.basicInfoForm.value`, because it doesn't show the value of disabled controls.

So if you want to check all form controls values (including disabled ones) , Use [getRawValue](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#getRawValue) method :

```
this.basicInfoForm.getRawValue();
```